# Android Spannable foreground/background together?

Tags: android

I need to style a portion of an EditText. I want the text to be white and the background gray.  Seems simple enough, but it ain't.

```
spanRange.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spanRange.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

mCaptionET.setText(spanRange, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

But what I get is GREEN, not WHITE.

[image]

What do I need to do to make this WHITE on GRAY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have `android:autoLink="web"` on your `TextView` to change the text link color, you have to add `android:textColorLink="@android:color/white"`

**Or in Java**

```
mCaptionET.setLinkTextColor(color);
```

Comment: Nice.  Figured it was something like that but didn't know where to look.